# How to serve static page in phoenix framework?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I want to serve static page in Phoenix Framework to use it in Angular Views. I know I can serve regular HTML, but I want to get rid of the default `LayoutView`. I could do with a solution to just have some Phoenix Views which don't "inherit" from `LayoutView`. Is it possible?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can serve static files by having a file in `priv/static` and matching the path in the `Plug.Static` options:

```
  plug Plug.Static,
    at: "/", from: :hello_phoenix, gzip: false,
    only: ~w(css fonts images js favicon.ico robots.txt my_fine.html)
```

You can also bypass the layout using [put_layout/2](http://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Controller.html#put_layout/2):

```
conn
|> put_layout(false)
|> render("index.html")
```

The `put_layout/2` function can also be called as a plug (due to the function arguments). This is useful if you want it to apply to the entire controller:

```
plug :put_layout, false
```

Comment: very helpful, thanks.  btw, for future readers, the plug static config is located in /lib/<app-name>/endpoint.ex

Comment: I want to serve an index.html from the endpoint  /apidocs. I want to put the static files in /priv/static/swagger. I'm having trouble deducing from the above answer how to do that.

Comment: @raarts yeah, what the first part of the answer would do is allow you to then request "/swagger/index.html" and you'd get the docs, but the full path to the file would be required. I'm trying to find out kinda the same thing myself.

Comment: @raarts found it, you want to do like http://stackoverflow.com/a/37924920/15064. Create a controller with a method that has that code, use a path relative to the root of the codebase (i.e. "./priv/static/swagger/index.html"), then create a get route for "/apidocs" pointing at that controller method.